# Architecture with IoC Containers and Composition Root

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container, structuremap

I'm quite new to DI and IoC Containers. I understand that the IoC container should only life at the composition root of the project. And I understand that all other projects in the solution shouldn't have a reference to the IoC container.

So far so good....

Then I  thought about, how to create new objects at runtime after the bootstrap.

I found this two articles:

http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory/

http://netpl.blogspot.de/2012/12/di-factories-and-composition-root.html

If I'm right, I have to create a factory for each object I want to instantiate at runtime, after the bootstrap. These factories gets the IoC Container injected.

Thus the project of the factory has to reference the IoC-Library (because of the constructor injection).

Finally I'm confused!

Where do these factories live (in which project)? I wonder, since all other projects (beside the composition root project) shouldn't have a reference to the IoC- Library.

At which point I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where do these factories live (in which project)? I wonder, since all
>   other projects (beside the composition root project) shouldn't have a
>   reference to the IoC- Library.

If the factory *implementation* needs to reference the container, it has to be defined in the [Composition Root](https://mng.bz/K1qZ). The factory *abstraction*, however, can be defined in the layer where it is needed.